# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 380. MiB for an array with shape (331792, 300) and data type float32

Tags: gensim, word2vec

i have trouble with this error while using word2vec from gensim

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 380. MiB for an array with shape (331792, 300) and data type float32
```

and this is my code

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

@app.route('/admin/index')
def show_admin():

model_baru = Word2Vec.load('model/idwiki_word2vec_300.model')
tester = model_baru.most_similar(positive=['wanita'],topn=3)
hasil = print(tester)

return render_template('admin/index.html',hasil=hasil)
```

what happen with this error?
please help me

thanks for your attention

Comment: Showing the full error you've received, including any traceback of involved lines-of-code, would help understand exactly which line of your code is failing. But a `MemoryError` most likely means you don't have enough RAM in your system to work with a model of that size, and the most direct fix is to work on a system with more RAM, or with a smaller model that fits.

Comment: ok thanks for information, i will try with a more litte size